# Is there some algorithm to compare the DOM similarity of different pages?

Tags: dom, pattern-matching, similarity

Has anyone some experience about this?

Comment: Do you mean that the output of comparing <div>some content</div> and <div>other content</div> should be that they are the same? The DOM is the same but the content is different

Answer (score 0):

You could first get all DOM elements and then remove their content and attributes. After the content has been removed you could convert all tags to lower or uppercase, then you can use any of the well known string matching algorithms like [Knuth-Morris-Pratt string matching](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960227.html)